# Christopher Potts' 39 features in his sentiment analyzer

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm relatively new to sentiment analysis and have been reading the excellent online tutorial by Stanford professor Christopher Potts.

In [his tutorial under the section on machine learning classifiers](http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/classifiers.html#numeric), he provides a brief discussion of a "lightweight, accurate classifier" and suggests the following steps:

> 1. Begin with a set of N fixed sentiment lexicons L. For my experiments, I used the fixed polarity lexicons, the IMDB scores, the
>      Experience Project O/E vectors, and the sentiment-rich classes from
>      the Harvard General Inquirer and LIWC. **The total number of
>      predictors was 39**, all of them numeric.
> 2. ...
> 3. For a given text, the feature function simply sums up all the words' scores for each of the **39 predictors** and then normalizes
>      them by the length of the text. Thus, each text is modeled as a vector
>      of 39 numbers.
> 4. ...

I am wondering where he got those 39 features from? From my understanding, the lexicons have thousands of entries, resulting in thousands of features using a bag-of-words model. How did he go from thousands of features to 39 features? He must have obviously done some feature selection, but I cannot infer his methodology or selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect he's not using bag of words features yet here. Likely, each of these data sources is a few features: Harvard General Inquirer certainly has a few categories, and there could be a feature for how many times a word in each of these categories appears. Similarly, Experience Project vectors have a few dimensions each, which creates a few features.

The point here is to try to make a lightweight, generalizable classifier. If you want to fit a particular dataset, n-gram features are almost certainly better. But, if you have limited training data, or want to generalize across different domains, having these "dense" features have value.